# pouchdb remote db replication "unauthorised" Cookie credentials ignored in electron app

Tags: javascript, couchdb, electron, session-cookies, pouchdb

## Issue

I have an electron app, I managed to login to couchdb with cookie auth.
I also manage to retrieve the correct session. I used the [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) so far to handle the requests.
For cookie storage in electron I use [electron-cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-cookies) and this is working, if I do another request with `credentials: 'include'` and `'withCredentials' : true` options (after login in) it makes the request with the cookie (Cookie:AuthSession=...).

Whenever a user is created in my app a corresponding database is created too with the new user being the admin of that database. So far so good.
*This setup works to 100% in postman.*

However, if I try to sync to the remoteDB with PouchDB this does not work, I get an unauthorized error.

My guess is that the authentification cookie is somehow ignored by PouchDB.

I tried way:

```
remoteDB = new PouchDB('http://somecorrecturl/userDBName');
```

and also like this:

```
remoteDB = new PouchDB('http://somecorrecturl/userDBName', {
    ajax: {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'withCredentials' : true
      },
      credentials: 'include',
      withCredentials: true,
    }
  });
```

without success.

( I also don’t see a request going out in the Network tab, this could be normal due to the nature of electron(?) tho’ )

Is there some special option I have to include? Using the `fetch api` for example I had to add `credentials: 'include'` before it would use the session cookie.

Is cookie auth even possible with pouchdb?
Or is there a way to sync a pouchdb with a couchdb "natively" without using the pouchdb api?

Doing the exact same thing with the same auth-cookie but using postman works. So my bet is that the cookie is ignored by pouchdb.

## Info

```
Environment: Node.js / Electron
Platform: Chromium / Electron
Adapter: PouchDB
Server: CouchDB
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I actually couldn't get this to work with pouch on node/request, but I didn't fully debug it, instead I am using the separate `auth:{username:..,password:..}` syntax.